# python regex sub %H:%M:%S to %M:%s or 01:%M:%s

Tags: python, regex

I want to convert string (subtitles) from:

```
585
00:59:59,237 --> 01:00:01,105
- It's all right. - He saw us!

586
01:00:01,139 --> 01:00:03,408
I heard you the first time.
```

into

> 59:59 - It's all right. - He saw us!
>
> 01:00:01 I heard you the first time.

**What I want is: if the time was within an hour, trim off the "00:" prefix, while keep it if the time was larger than 1 hour **

my regex is:

```
pat = re.compile(r"""
    #\s*                    # Skip leading whitespace
    \d+\s                   # remoe lines contain only numbers
    ((?:(?:00)|(?P<hour>01)):(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2})[,0-9->]+.*)[\r\n]+(?P<content>.*)[\r\n]+
    """, 
    re.VERBOSE)
data = pat.sub(r"\g<hour>\g<time> \g<content>", data)
```

it would work only when '`\g<hour>`' is not used. 
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is what you are looking for:

```
import re

s = """
585
00:59:59,237 --> 01:00:01,105
- It's all right. - He saw us!

586
01:00:01,139 --> 01:00:03,408
I heard you the first time.
"""

for line in re.findall(r'(\d+:)(\d+:\d+)(?:.*\n)(.*)', s):
    if line[0] == '00:':
        print ' '.join(line[1:])
    else:
        print ' '.join([''.join(line[0:2]), line[2]])
```

Output:

```
# 59:59 - It's all right. - He saw us!
# 01:00:01 I heard you the first time.
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't illustrate my question well. What I want is: if the time was within an hour, trim off the "00:" prefix, while keep it if the time was larger than 1 hour

Comment: @Brent81 I've edited the script for your needs. If you think my solution is useful, please vote up, and accept it. Thanks! Oh, and next time, please be more specific!

Answer (score 1):

just to give the non-re approach (which should be much faster):

```
a = """585
00:59:59,237 --> 01:00:01,105
- It's all right. - He saw us!

586
01:00:01,139 --> 01:00:03,408
I heard you the first time."""

for i, x in enumerate(a.split('\n')):
    m = i % 4
    if m == 0:
        continue
    elif m == 3:
        continue
    elif m == 1:
        print x[:x.find(":", x.find(":") + 1)],
    elif m == 2:
        print x
```

Comment: the output is: `58 00:59:59,237 --> 01:00:01,105` and `58 01:00:01,139 --> 01:00:03,408` and this is not what the OP wants — edited: sorry, yours is working, but only if there is no leading and trailing whitespace (`\n`)

Comment: @PeterVaro - This is just an outline for a non `re` approach

Comment: **mine:** `466 function calls (438 primitive calls) in 0.001 seconds`, **yours:** `7 function calls in 0.000 seconds`

Comment: @zenpoy - Thanks for pointing out re is slower! now i'm not using RE in my code.